# How do I get meaningful error message with Twig?

Tags: php, twig

I'm using Twig without Symphony. It is installed via composer and used with composers autoloader. In bootstrap phase Twig is instantiated as:

```
// lib_get_basedir returns root directory of library.
$templatePath = sprintf("%s/data/templates", lib_get_basedir());
// $conf stores configuration values.
// tmp_dir is library directory for temporary files.
$cachePath = sprintf("%s/twig_cache", $conf->get("tmp_dir"));
$loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem($templatePath);
$twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader, [
    "cache" => $cachePath
]);
$gettextFun = new \Twig_SimpleFunction("gettext", function ($value) {
      return gettext($value);
});
$twig->addFunction($gettextFun);
$twig->getExtension("core")->setNumberFormat(2, ",", ".");
$twig->addExtension(new \Twig_Extensions_Extension_I18n());
$twig->addExtension(new \Twig_Extensions_Extension_Intl());
$twig->addExtension(new \Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text());
```

When I try to render a template using this Twig_Environment instance, I only get this meaningless error:

```
Error 2: include_once(/var/lib/wlc/tmp/twig_cache/16/167b8e710323d3fc9a90a6d582652a570b1993e4d46cebd1350484a0c3ad445e.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
File: phar:///usr/local/share/wlc/libwlc-local-1.2.phar/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Cache/Filesystem.php
Line: 49
```

I already checked permissions on the `twig_cache` folder and its parents and that should not be the problem. This error now also happens on machines where there is only one user who runs php-fcgi and owns the cache directory.

This error doesn't happen if I pass `false` for `$cachePath`.

My question is, how can I debug this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced same problem with Twig v1.24.1 in slim twig-view.
https://github.com/slimphp/Twig-View

What version do you use?

I found this commit.
https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/commit/b5df3d1dbec8b925a0eaf6e763748a74e53988e7

but this commit isn't included master branch now.

I solved with updating twig version in my composer.json as follows,

```
"twig/twig": "1.x-dev"
```

Comment: That commit got me on the right track, thank you. They are including the file with @ operator. This would be fine if I hadn't installed an error handler with set_error_handler which dies on errors. I'll comment on Twig bug #2043 about error handlers.